# how to detect textbox field empty spaces?

Tags: javascript

I need help in textbox keypress function.
If textbox fields is empty menad no need to post values.

my following functions working .if textbox fields is empty,i  press enter key going nexline thats fine.but i press enter key two times values posted.

what is the problem in my code.plz help me.

```
      $(".ppop-comment").keypress(function(e)
         {
          if($('#add_comment').val()=="")
           {
               if (e.which == 32) 

        return false;
              }
           else if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey && !$('#add_comment').val()==" ")
           {
                     $("#submit-comment").click(); 
                    }


         });

              <form id="commentform" method="post">
                 <textarea id="add_comment" name="meetnewpeople[message]" class="popup-comment">
                <input id="submit-comment" type="button" value="Post a comment" />


                   </form>
```

Comment: Maybe set up a jsfiddle that displays the problem?

Comment: You want to submit if there is a space in the field? Please format your code with better indentation. Like I did for you before you edited again

Comment: yes.only no character,thats,fully empty spaces means dont posted values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".ppop-comment").keypress(function(e)
     {
      if($('#add_comment').val().trim()!="")
       {
          if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey && !$('#add_comment').val()==" ")
           {
                 $("#submit-comment").click(); 
           }
       }
       else
       {
          return false;
       }

     });
```

Comment: hai,i use this function $('#add_comment').val().trim()!="") ,i cannot enter textbox fields.plz help me.